# Como setar valor para filtro do Jquery Datatables?

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Tenho meu input e button

```
<input id="gridSearch" type="text" /> <button id="filter" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
```

e minha tabela

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true;
var grid = $("#gridCustomer").DataTable({
    "language": {
        "sProcessing": '<img src="/Scripts/loadingBgBlack.GIF" /> Loading...'
    },
    "bFilter": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true
```

Como eu seto o valor para filtrar no grid ?

```
$('#filter').click(function (e) {

    var searchValue = $("#gridSearch").val();

});
```

Por que fiz isso?

Por que quero colocar o input em outra posição, e quero que ele busque apenas quando click em "Buscar".

Então eu removi o que vem padrão, usando `"bFilter": false` e adicionando manualmente o meu próprio input com button

Answer (score 1):

Amigo.

Para que você consiga fazer isto, você terá que passar o valor do seu campo para o fonte que está fazendo a carga das informações.

No meu caso utilizo o PHP para fazer a carga das informações. No Fonte PHP existe um `$_GET ['sSearch']` que é o valor do campo Default.

Basta você substitui-lo pelo valor do campo que você esta utilizando - `&sSearch=SEU_VALOR`